# when does deployment_blocked failure occur in ecs task protection

Tags: amazon-ecs

First Question
When the ECS service has been running for some time, and I scale in to 0 (to do a deploy), I get a message "service {service name} was unable to reach steady state because taskSet {task-set-name} was unable to scale in due to (reason {large-number} tasks under protection)."
large-number (48, 60, 76) is significantly larger than the ECS configuration Desired instances (2).
Where is that large number coming from?
I've tried using the ECS ListTasks + GetTaskProtection api to look for protected tasks before I do this, and I'm not seeing old records from stopped containers. I only see records for the active tasks.

Second question
When using the ECS Task Protection API, what scenario causes the DEPLOYMENT_BLOCKED failure to occur? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-scale-in-protection.html

I cannot get a consistent behavior to trigger the DEPLOYMENT_BLOCKED failure.

During a scale-in, sometimes we get a failure code DEPLOYMENT_BLOCKED, but it's not consistent. To address this, I have the process sleeping for 5 seconds after an Unprotect API call is made, to give ECS time to send a SIGTERM. Catching the SIGTERM stops the polling loop and the process ends.

If I'm going from 2 tasks -> 0 tasks, shouldn't either task receive DEPLOYMENT_BLOCKED when they attempt to call Protect? Does scaling in without changing other aspects of the service not qualify as a scenario where DEPLOYMENT_BLOCKED will occur?

I feel like in this case, Protecting the remaining tasks should cause more tasks to be protected than Desired. I expect those tasks to receive a failure, but it is not. Am I missing the scenario where DEPLOYMENT_BLOCKED occurs?